# Start with Apache Camel

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, apache-camel

I’m very new to Apache Camel and will very appreciate if someone could provide me what camel components may be used to solve particular task.
I have a simple REST WS. This service is not accessible to audience. 
The idea is to build middle layer between user requests and endpoint service.
So I will have to catch user’s request, make some manipulations with it, send to restricted WS and give a response to user.
I’m just started learning apache camel and the question is what is the best way to implement this logic.
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, Camel is not the right framework to implement web controllers. Of course there is the [Camel Rest Module](https://camel.apache.org/rest.html), but it is stretching the responsibilities of the framework too far.

I recommend using a more adapt framework for the implementation of the WS, e.g. *Spring* or *Jersey*, and call Camel endpoints programmatically from the request handlers. Within Spring, triggering Camel Endpoints is easy since the CamelContext can get autowired into your web controller:

```
camelContext.createProducerTemplate().sendBodyAndHeader("direct:myEndpoint", null, "id", id);
```

For your Camel Root this approach means, that it starts of with a [Direct endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/direct.html), then forwards to a [Camel http](https://camel.apache.org/http.html) endpoint and if necessary forwards the output from the HTTP call to some Spring bean transformation step, before finally passing it back to the web controller handler method:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:myEndpoint"/>
        <to uri="http:somehost.com"/>
        <transform>
            <method ref="springBean" method="doSomeTransformation"/>
        </transform>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several camel components you can use for this task. Think of Camel as a toolbox where you can choose from several tools for the same task.

You can use:

- Camel-HTTP4 http://camel.apache.org/http4.html
- Camel-Jetty http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html
- Camel-Restlet http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html
- Camel-CXFRS  http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html

Example using java dsl:

```
from("jetty://http://localhost:7070/test").to("jetty://http://localhost:7070/test1");
```

Example using blueprint

```
<route>
    <from uri="jetty://http://localhost:7070/test"/>
    <to uri="jetty://http://localhost:7070/test1"/>
<route>
```